# Create txt file of specified objects from JSON

Tags: python, json, service

I've created an html file for a service report via json and it works as needed.

```
#Creates Html page
f = open("Oceaneering_Server_Status.html", "w")
f.write('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<style type=text/css>
body{{
    background-color: #D9D8D5;
}}
table, th, td {{

    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}}
th {{
    text-align: center;
}}
td {{
    text-align: center;
    contains("STARTED").css('color', 'red');

}}
</style>

<body>
<h1>Oceaneering Server Status: </h1>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<p>Last updated: {time}<br>Services Running: XXXX</br><p id="row"></br></p>
<table  id="table" class="tablesorter" style="margin: 0px auto;" table class="sortable">>
<caption>Last updated: XXXX Total Services: XXXX Services Stopped: XXX Services Running: XXX </caption>
<col width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Folder</th>
    <th>Service URL</th>
    <th>Configured State</th>
    <th>Real Time State</th>
    <th>Server Type</th>
  </tr>'''.format(time=date))

for item in json_read["folders"]:
        services_url = "https://www.ocsdev.oceaneering.com/arcgis/admin/services/" + item + "/report?f=pjson&token=" + token
        t = []
        t.append(services_url)
        print t

        for i in t:
            services_open = urllib.urlopen(services_url)
            services_js = json.loads(services_open.read())
            #print services_js


        #z = open("test.text", "w")
        for i in services_js["reports"]:
            f = open("Oceaneering_Server_Status.html", "a")
            line1 = "<tr>" + "\n\t<td>" + i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "</td>\n"
            serv_count = i["instances"]["serviceName"]+ "\n"
            line2 = "\t<td>" + i["instances"]["folderName"] + "</td>\n"
            line3 = '\t<td><a href= "https://www.ocsdev.oceaneering.com/arcgis/rest/services/' + i["instances"]["folderName"] +"/"+ i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "/MapServer?f=jsapi&token=" + token + '">' + i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "</a>" + "</td>\n"
            line4 = "\t<td>" + i["status"]["configuredState"] + "</td>\n"
            line5 = "\t<td>" + i["status"]["realTimeState"] + "</td>\n"
            line6 = "\t<td>" + i["instances"]["type"] + "</td>\n"
            f.write(line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6 )
            #z.write(serv_count)


#z.close()

##with open('test.text') as b:
##    aws = len(b.readlines())
##print aws


f.write('''</table>

<script>

$( "td:contains('STARTED')" ).css( "color", "green" );
$( "td:contains('STOPPED')" ).css( "color", "red" );



var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});

var tableSize = "Total Services: " + $('#table tr').length;
document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = tableSize;

</script>

</body>
</html>''')
f.close()


print "completed"

#_______________________________________________________________________________#
#Create TXT file of Services

import json
with open('Oceaneering_Server_Status.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_read, outfile)

print "completed"
```

I'm trying to then create a txt file of the 'STOPPED' services..
I'm able to create the txt file, but I can't seem to print only the specific services for which I need...
Thoughts?

Comment: What are "the specific services for which I need..."? How are they identified?

Comment: please show us code of what you are attempting to do to solve your problem, that we can replicate your problem. It shows us what you understand of your problem, which you should understand better than anyone else.

Comment: I only need the services listed as 'STOPPED' from the html file printed onto the txt file.

Comment: this is the code i have, excluding the token info

Comment: Which json part indicates that they are "STOPPED"? `i["status"]["realTimeState"]` maybe? If you wrote that code, please don't let us guess...

Comment: import json
with open('Oceaneering_Server_Status.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_read, outfile)

print "completed"

Comment: sorry ab that, the ["configuredState"] and ["realTimeState"] is giving me the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just maintain a list of stopped services, filling it while creating your html file and dumping only its contents to the JSON file:

```
#Creates Html page
f = open("Oceaneering_Server_Status.html", "w")
f.write('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<style type=text/css>
body{{
    background-color: #D9D8D5;
}}
table, th, td {{

    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}}
th {{
    text-align: center;
}}
td {{
    text-align: center;
    contains("STARTED").css('color', 'red');

}}
</style>

<body>
<h1>Oceaneering Server Status: </h1>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
<p>Last updated: {time}<br>Services Running: XXXX</br><p id="row"></br></p>
<table  id="table" class="tablesorter" style="margin: 0px auto;" table class="sortable">>
<caption>Last updated: XXXX Total Services: XXXX Services Stopped: XXX Services Running: XXX </caption>
<col width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Folder</th>
    <th>Service URL</th>
    <th>Configured State</th>
    <th>Real Time State</th>
    <th>Server Type</th>
  </tr>'''.format(time=date))

stopped = []
for item in json_read["folders"]:
        services_url = "https://www.ocsdev.oceaneering.com/arcgis/admin/services/" + item + "/report?f=pjson&token=" + token
        t = []
        t.append(services_url)
        print t

        for i in t:
            services_open = urllib.urlopen(services_url)
            services_js = json.loads(services_open.read())
            #print services_js


        #z = open("test.text", "w")
        for i in services_js["reports"]:
            f = open("Oceaneering_Server_Status.html", "a")
            line1 = "<tr>" + "\n\t<td>" + i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "</td>\n"
            serv_count = i["instances"]["serviceName"]+ "\n"
            line2 = "\t<td>" + i["instances"]["folderName"] + "</td>\n"
            line3 = '\t<td><a href= "https://www.ocsdev.oceaneering.com/arcgis/rest/services/' + i["instances"]["folderName"] +"/"+ i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "/MapServer?f=jsapi&token=" + token + '">' + i["instances"]["serviceName"] + "</a>" + "</td>\n"
            line4 = "\t<td>" + i["status"]["configuredState"] + "</td>\n"
            line5 = "\t<td>" + i["status"]["realTimeState"] + "</td>\n"
            line6 = "\t<td>" + i["instances"]["type"] + "</td>\n"
            f.write(line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6 )
            #z.write(serv_count)

            if i["status"]["realTimeState"] == "STOPPED":
                stopped.append(i)


#z.close()

##with open('test.text') as b:
##    aws = len(b.readlines())
##print aws


f.write('''</table>

<script>

$( "td:contains('STARTED')" ).css( "color", "green" );
$( "td:contains('STOPPED')" ).css( "color", "red" );



var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});

var tableSize = "Total Services: " + $('#table tr').length;
document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = tableSize;

</script>

</body>
</html>''')
f.close()


print "completed"

#_______________________________________________________________________________#
#Create TXT file of Services

import json
with open('Oceaneering_Server_Status.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(stopped, outfile)

print "completed"
```